# React Error Message Persists even after Refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, message

I am working on a project in React. In  the Register Page, I add all errors in a Message component. During development, whenever a React error occurs *(like Cannot read properties of undefined)*, the error message continues to be displayed in the component until I successfully register. I want the error message to disappear whenever I reload the page.

I tried putting the below condition to get rid of the error message but it didn't work. I don't understand why the error message persists.

```
{error ? <Message variant="danger">{error}</Message> : ""}
```

Edit: I am using redux, so the error is being returned by an API call.

```
  const userCreate = useSelector((state) => state.userCreate);
  const { error, success, loading } = userCreate;
```

After I return this error in the Message component, it isn't disappearing. Once I even had to clear localStorage to get rid of it. The error was *Cannot read properties of undefined, reading password*.

Comment: please provide [Minimalreproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) we need atleast to know, where you get error variable

Comment: @Wraithy, have added further explanation, does that suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using functional component then you can use the useEffect() hook and set the error value to false, so that whenever you are reloading the page error value will be false and your error message will not appear and for class based component you can use componentDidMount() to do the same.

```
const [showMessage,setShowMessage] = useState(false);
useEffect(()=>{
   if(error){
      showMessage(true);
   }
},[error])

{showMessage ? <Message variant="danger">{error}</Message> : ""}
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not very thorough with React but the errors are not being set by useState, API calls are returning those error messages. So how can I set the value to false?

Comment: I've edited the comment and added the code give you an idea. You can call the useEffect hook every time the error value is changed because we have passed error as an dependency and then you can check that if its error then show message else not.